# Arduino Mega2560 and SD card module read and write

Tags: arduino, project

I'm currently having a project which reads, voltage and current then computes for power, peak power and total energy consumption of an appliance/s.

One feature of my project is that the user can save and read readings of peak power and total enrgy consumption which is stored in a 1GB micro SD card. The user can save and read the readings anytime he/she wants.

My question is how much can arduino read and write take with this kind of memory and process?

here is my code of how I write and read text in a file.

Write:

```
int WriteToFile(String text){
  if(myFile){
    myFile.println(text);
    return 1;
    }else{
      return 0;
     }
}
```

Read:

```
void Read(){
  myFile.seek(0);
  char cr;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < linenumber;){
    cr = myFile.read();
    if(cr == '\n'){
      i++;
      }
  }
  while(true){
    cr = myFile.read();
  if((cr == '\n')||(cr == '\r')||(cr < 0))
    break;
    lcd2.print(cr);
  }
}
```

Im using the catalex micro SD card module and Arduino Mega2560 MCU.

Comment: Are you using a Arduino SD Library ? What is the object `myFile` ? Is the provided source code working partially ?

Comment: Yes Im currently using the Arduino SD Library.

Comment: MyFile is the variable name used for the SD class functions.

Comment: Yes code so far is working properly.

Comment: Is your question _**"how much can arduino read and write take"**_ focused to a performance matter ? What is the frequency of `WriteToFile()` calls ?

Comment: performance mater, yes.
Im not sure what the frequency of the WriteToFIle() function. Maybe few hundred kB per second.

Comment: When looking other forum, your request of more than 100K bytes par second seems too optimistic. Read operation could be faster 250Kb/s, but the write operation will close to the tenth. How did you get that sampling frequency by including multiple ADC reading (voltage, current, ...) ?